# Why are particles being added at a greater rate than it is removed in my function?

Tags: javascript, constructor, p5.js

I've been trying to create a simple particle emitter in Javascript. But when writing the function for removing particles when it exceeds lifetime, particles are being added at a higher rate. Here is my code:

```
this.addParticle = function() {
    var p = new Particle(
        random(this.x - 10, this.x + 10),
        random(this.y - 10, this.y + 10),
        random(this.xSpeed - 1, this.xSpeed + 1),
        random(this.ySpeed - 1, this.ySpeed + 1),
        random(this.size - 4, this.size + 4),
        this.colour
    );
    this.particles.push(p);
    return p;
}

this.updateParticles = function() {
    //iterate through particles and draw to screen
    for(let i = this.particles.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.particles[i].drawParticle();
        this.particles[i].updateParticle();
        if (this.particles[i].age > this.lifetime) {
            this.particles.splice(i, 1); // removes particle
            this.particles.push(this.addParticle()); // adds new particle
        }
    }
}
```

I know that somehow more particles are being pushed into the array and that this could be resolved by simply checking `if (this.particles.length < this.startParticles)`. However, I can't wrap around my head on why its possible that particles are being added faster than its removed in my updateParticles function - are the particles not added on a 1-1 basis?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Make a ***[mcve]*** using the ***snippet editor*** - that means a runnable example and not just bits of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be because you're calling `this.particles.push()` twice, once in your `updateParticles` function and in the `addParticle` function?

Comment: That wasn't supposed to sound as sarcastic as it ended up sounding sorry

Comment: Nope its fine, but how would it be pushed twice when im returning in addParticle? It should only be pushing once in a previous initialisation function and another time during updateParticles.

Comment: You call the `addParticle()` function, which contains the line `this.particles.push(p);`, then you return the Particle to the caller, and it gets added to the array again via `this.particles.push(this.addParticle());` in `updateParticles()`. Note that they both reference the *same* particle instance, but you've added two references to the array.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. That was silly of me, thank you.